# Why do newline characters get lost when using command substitution?

Tags: shell, newlines, command-substitution

I have a text file named links.txt which looks like this

```
link1
link2
link3
```

I want to loop through this file line by line and perform an operation on every line. I know I can do this using while loop but since I am learning, I thought to use a for loop.
I actually used command substitution like this

```
a=$(cat links.txt)
```

Then used the loop like this

```
for i in $a; do ###something###;done
```

Also I can do something like this

```
for i in $(cat links.txt); do ###something###; done
```

Now my question is when I substituted the cat command output in a variable a, the new line characters between link1 link2 and link3 are removed and is replaced by spaces

```
echo $a
```

outputs

link1 link2 link3

and then I used the for loop.
Is it always that a new line is replaced by space when we do a command substitution??

Regards

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)...

Comment: Unquoted variables are subject to [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) and [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/344407/how-to-read-complete-line-in-for-loop-with-spaces

Comment: If you look closely, you'll see that this question is not a duplicate.  ***This*** question is about the newlines *between* the lines of output from the command (i.e., at the ends of lines 1 through *n* −1).  ***That*** question, as its title suggests, is about the newline at the *end* of the output from the command (i.e., at the end of the last line).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/capturing-multiple-line-output-into-a-bash-variable

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The newlines were lost, because the shell had performed [field splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05) after command substitution.

In POSIX [Command Substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) section:

> The shell shall expand the command substitution by executing command
>   in a subshell environment (see Shell Execution Environment) and
>   replacing the command substitution (the text of command plus the
>   enclosing "$()" or backquotes) with the standard output of the
>   command, removing sequences of one or more  characters at the
>   end of the substitution. **Embedded  characters before the end
>   of the output shall not be removed; however, they may be treated as
>   field delimiters and eliminated during field splitting, depending on
>   the value of IFS and quoting that is in effect**. If the output contains
>   any null bytes, the behavior is unspecified.

Default `IFS` value (at least in `bash`):

```
$ printf '%q\n' "$IFS"
$' \t\n'
```

In your case, you don't set `IFS` or using double quotes, so newlines character will be eliminated during field splitting.

You can preserve newlines, example by setting`IFS`to empty:

```
$ IFS=
$ a=$(cat links.txt)
$ echo "$a"
link1
link2
link3
```

Comment: Note: If you use `printf` instead of `echo` you avoid the IFS issue entirely

Comment: @OliverDungey it's not about `echo` or `printf`, it's about double quote`"$a"`. the original question is using for loop, that's when field splitting occurs after command substitution.

Answer (score 68):

Newlines get swapped out at some points because they are special characters. In order to keep them, you need to make sure they're always interpreted, by using quotes:

```
$ a="$(cat links.txt)"
$ echo "$a"
link1
link2
link3
```

Now, since I used quotes whenever I was manipulating the data, the newline characters (`\n`) always got interpreted by the shell, and therefore remained. If you forget to use them at some point, these special characters will be lost.

The very same behaviour will occur if you use your loop on lines containing spaces. For instance, given the following file...

```
mypath1/file with spaces.txt
mypath2/filewithoutspaces.txt
```

The output will depend on whether or not you use quotes:

```
$ for i in $(cat links.txt); do echo $i; done
mypath1/file
with
spaces.txt
mypath2/filewithoutspaces.txt

$ for i in "$(cat links.txt)"; do echo "$i"; done
mypath1/file with spaces.txt
mypath2/filewithoutspaces.txt
```

Now, if you don't want to use quotes, there is a special shell variable which can be used to change the shell field separator (`IFS`). If you set this separator to the newline character, you will get rid of most problems.

```
$ IFS=$'\n'; for i in $(cat links.txt); do echo $i; done
mypath1/file with spaces.txt
mypath2/filewithoutspaces.txt
```

For the sake of completeness, here is another example, which does not rely on command output substitution. After some time, I found out that this method was considered more reliable by most users due to the very behaviour of the `read` utility.

```
$ cat links.txt | while read i; do echo $i; done
```

Here is an excerpt from `read`'s man page:

> The read utility shall read a single line from standard input.

Since `read` gets its input line by line, you're sure it won't break whenever a space shows up. Just pass it the output of `cat` through a pipe, and it'll iterate over your lines just fine.

*Edit:* I can see from other answers and comments that people are quite reluctant when it comes to the use of `cat`. As [jasonwryan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6761/jasonwryan) said in his comment, a more *proper* way to read a file in shell is to use stream redirection (`<`), as you can see in [val0x00ff's answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164514/41892). However, since the question isn't "*[how to read/process a file in shell programming](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)*", my answer focuses more on the quotes behaviour, and not the rest.

Comment: Also let's say I am not using quotes, then when I am applying the for loop, is it implicit that variable i will hold the value as the first file until it reaches a space which tells it that first file ends??

Comment: With all do respect to John WH Smith, I'm not sure who is upvoting the answer.  `for i in $(cat ..)` is wrong. See the comment of `jasonwryan`.  That is the way how you read lines from a file. cat(1) is used to concatenate multiple files together. It should NOT be used to feed file data to processes. There are far better ways to achieve this. The application might take a file as argument (eg. grep ^foo file); or you might want to use file redirection (eg. read line < file).

Comment: @val0x00ff - it's not wrong because you say it is, certainly. what is *wrong* about it?

Comment: @val0x00ff I used `cat` because that is what the OP was using in his question ;) The question isn't really about "how to read a file", but "why are newlines lost". As far as I'm concerned, I would always use `read`, which is why I edited my answer afterwards to add this solution. I understand that `cat` shouldn't be used to read a single file, but since it isn't the main topic, I didn't spend too much time on it.

Comment: @mikeserv - it treats data as code, which is generally considered wrong in any language. Or, any language except bash, apparently.

Comment: @geirha - this is not a true statement at all. It delimits fields on specified delimiters. If it is such an unpopular behavior, how is it `awk` is so ubiquitous? From the [POSIX rationale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html):  *If the IFS variable is unset or is <space> <tab> <newline>, the operation is equivalent to the way the System V shell splits words. Using characters outside the \s \n \t set yields the KornShell behavior, where each of the non- \s \n \t is significant. This behavior .. was taken from the way the original awk handled field splitting.*

Comment: @mikeserv - "Take the data in this file and split it into words based on the characters in IFS, then for each of those words that happen to contain glob characters, attempt to replace those words with matching filenames". That certainly doesn't sound like treating data as data.

Comment: Yes - @geirha - globbing *is* a problem. That is a very excellent point. This is why the shell offers the `set -f` option. You can either expand filenames with `set +f` or not do with `set -f`. I specifically address that in my own answer here. And, as far as I can tell, it's the only one here that mentions it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/capturing-multiple-line-output-into-a-bash-variable

Comment: The IFS=$'\n'; is needed for looping properly the quotes will not do line by line properly without it (BASH4+)

Answer (score 7):

To add my emphasis, `for` loops iterate over **words**. If your file is:

```
one two
three four
```

Then this will emit **four** lines:

```
for word in $(cat file); do echo "$word"; done
```

To iterate over the **lines** of a file, do this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # do something with "$line" <-- quoted almost always
done < file
```

Comment: `for` loops iterate over arguments. If you do `IFS=\n; for word in cat file; do echo "$word"; done` you'll get two loops and two lines printed. `$IFS` applies globally all of the time in much the same way as it does to `read` - except that the `read`/`\n`ewline relationship is pretty special.

Comment: I upvoted the second explanation `while IFS` because it yet shows another way of feeding lines from a file. Again. @mikeserv  about `for word in $(cat file)` is wrong and should not be used in bash scripts or any other form. Let me emphasise once again:  Never do this: for x in $(command) or `command` or $var. for-in is used for iterating arguments, not (output) strings. Instead, use a glob (eg. *.txt), arrays (eg. "${names[@]}") or a while-read loop (eg. while read -r line). See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf1 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: @val0x00ff - I don't think you understand - `$IFS` is *about arguments.* Specifically, `$IFS` splits fields into arguments - that's its job. There are potential problems with that approach - but they are handled as easily as `set -f; IFS=$delimiter` - that's all you need do. For example, you could do the very slow `while read -r line` thing *or* you could do `set -f; IFS=\n; set -- $(cat file)`. If you did that you'd get an array of the file's non-blank lines *each in tact* in `$1 $2 $3... "$@"`. The wooledge wiki is typically an awful source of information - you should try to wean off of it.

Comment: @val0x00ff - I should temper that last statement - the Dontreadlineswithfor thing is actually mostly correct - and there is an excellent point there made about memory requirements. What they don't mention there is that `bash`'s horrible `$IFS` handling is not typical to most other shells. In any case, any file small enough to warrant a `while read` loop is no threat to your total RAM however you should choose to map it. If it is of any consequential size, then you should probably be looking to `sed` or similar for processing - the shell is not often a good solution in that case.

Comment: To properly set IFS to a newline, use ANSI-C quoting: `IFS=$'\n'` -- this (`IFS=\n`) sets IFS to the letter "n"

Comment: That's true - it's a pain to represent a newline in a comment so I sometimes fudge it. The quoting method you mention is not I usually use - I just type single-quote, ctrl+v,ctrl+j,single-quote.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `read` from bash. Also look for the `mapfile`

```
while read -r link
  do
   printf '%s\n' "$link"
  done < links.txt
```

Or using mapfile

```
mapfile -t myarray < links.txt
for link in "${myarray[@]}"; do printf '%s\n' "$link"; done
```

Answer (score -2):

The newlines are replaced with spaces because that's how `echo` works - it concatenates its arguments on spaces. `echo` replaces argument delimiters with a space. In truth, you can iterate with `for` over anything you want, but you have to specify the field delimiter first:

```
string=abababababababababababa IFS=a        
for c in $string
do printf %s "$c"
done
```

#### OUTPUT

```
bbbbbbbbbbb
```

But this isn't behavior unique to a `for` loop - this happens for any field split expansion:

```
printf %s $string
bbbbbbbbbbb
```

For example, if you want to print only the first 10 bytes from any non-blank line in a file...

```
###original:
first "line"
<second>"line"
<second>"line"
<second>line and so on%
(IFS='                                                       
'; printf %.10s\\n $(cat file))
###output
first "lin
<second>"l
<second>"l
<second>li
```

There is a reason I specify *non-blank* above - the `\n`ewline is one of three  special bytes in `$IFS`. While everything else will get you an empty argument when 2 or more occur in succession, any sequence of spaces, tabs, or newlines can only ever evaluate to a single field.

And so for example:

```
(IFS=0;printf 'ten lines!%s\n' $(printf "%010d"))

ten lines!
ten lines!
ten lines!
ten lines!
ten lines!
ten lines!
ten lines!
ten lines!
ten lines!
ten lines!
```

But...

```
(IFS=\ ;printf 'one line%s\n' $(printf "%010s"))
one line
```

In both cases `printf` prints 10 filler characters - in the first case it prints 10 zeroes and in the second 10 spaces. In the first case every 0 generates a null field and the second `printf` gets 10 empty arguments for each of which it writes its format string, but all of the spaces printed in the second case amount to nothing at all.

You should note that this is not the *only* kind of field generation that the shell will do with unquoted expansions - by default it will also *glob*. Doing things like:

```
for line in $(cat file)
```

Can lead to very unexpected results because there is a very real chance that some of those lines will contain shell globs that match real files - and suddenly `$line` doesn't refer to a line of input any more but instead an on-disk filename.

If you plan to use `$IFS` for any splitting it is *always* a good idea to:

```
set -f
```

...first, which will instruct the shell not to glob while you do. When you are through you can re-enable it with `set +f`.

Comment: I think `The newlines are replaced with spaces because that's how echo works` seems to be wrong.

Comment: @cuonglm - it could be clearer, but the `\n`ewlines are replaced with field delimeters, and `echo` replaces the field delimiters with spaces - it concatenates its arguments on spaces. That's how `echo` works.