# prefixing multiple lines preserving line breaks

Tags: text-processing

I have a bash script which has a variable being set from the output of cat and grep:

```
result=`cat $file | grep -A2 "$search"`
```

result contains 3 lines E.G.:

```
This is Line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
```

I need to prefix each line with a space:

```
 This is Line 1
 This is line 2
 This is line 3
```

I have tried the following:

```
result=`echo $result | awk '{print " "$0}'`
```

and a few different sed commands, all of which result in this:

```
 This is Line 1 This is line 2 This is line 3
```

they add the spaces, but delete the new lines

Note: this will be saved into a file which needs the line breaks

Comment: `< $file grep -A2 "$search" | sed -e 's/^/ /'`. If you want to use the text captured in `$result` then `<<< "$result" sed -e 's/^/ /'`. `echo` converts newlines to spaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do newline characters get lost when using command substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164508/why-do-newline-characters-get-lost-when-using-command-substitution)

Comment: Dear @steeldriver, Yes, correct for the last part of OP's question which s/he wants to have newlines intact, the duplicated question as you flagged is right duplicate, but here OP wants to add a space for each line which is the main challenge and his question.

Comment: @αғsнιη the OP seems to have solved the "main challenge" (although personally I would have used `sed` rather than `awk`); their code should work fine if they simply quote `$result` to prevent word splitting by the shell i.e. `echo "$result" | awk '{print " "$0}'`

Comment: Voting to leave open - this is a much more specific use case while the linked question gives a highly general answer that doesn't help with the user's immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

awk

```
awk '{printf " %s\n",$0}' file-in.txt > file-out.txt
```

sed

```
sed -e 's/^/ /' file-in.txt > file-out.txt
```

sed (same file)

```
sed -i -s 's/^/ /' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` at first start instead of using `grep` and stop going to extra processing on `$result` (This is a kind of `grep`'s `-A Num` simulation).

```
result=$(awk -v patt="$search" '$0 ~ patt{S=1}
         S && ($0 ~ patt || ++n<3) {print " "$0} n==3{n=0}' infile)
```

Then print/save the `$result` into a output file:

```
printf '%s\n' "$result" > outfile
```