# Why does a Bash 'while' read loop with a command substitution herestring not read the entire input?

Tags: bash, command-substitution, read, here-string

Look at this very basic Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read l
do
  echo $l
  echo "next one"
done <<< $(ps aux)
```

I have several processes on my computer, and the `ps aux` command works fine in the terminal.

I only get ***one*** iteration in the loop and `ps` command output is given on the same line. Why doesn't it work as intended?

Comment: Couldn't replicate.  Running that script on my system (`bash` *v4.4*) returns the same multi-line results from both the command line and as a script.  Note: it'd be simpler to change `while ... done <<< $(ps aux)` to `ps aux | while ... done`.

Comment: This is strange. Do you know if a configuration or environnement variable can impact this behaviour ?

Comment: Are you using some old version of bash, like 3.2?

Comment: Let's compare `set -o` outputs.  On my system `printf '%x\n' $((2#$(set -o | rev | cut -c 1 | tr 'fn' '01' | tr -d '\n')))` outputs the hex summary of *31d4000*.  (That is it takes a list of "on/off" values, converts 'em to binary, then to a single hex value.)

Answer (score 9):

In `bash` versions < `4.4-beta` you need to add double quotes:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read l
do
  echo $l
  echo "next one"
done <<< "$(ps aux)"
```

See:

- [Why do newline characters get lost when using command substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164508/why-do-newline-characters-get-lost-when-using-command-substitution)
- [Do here-strings undergo word-splitting?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47745181/7365127)

  > Bash no longer splits the expansion of here-strings, as the documentation has always said.

---

In general, I think it is better to use process substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read l
do
  echo $l
  echo "next one"
done < <(ps aux)
```

(To avoid issues, [you might want to use `IFS=`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/how-to-loop-over-the-lines-of-a-file)).

or even better, use a program specialized for reading files or input line by line like e.g. `awk`.

```
ps aux | awk '{print $0; print "next one"}'
```

Comment: Thanks but why quotes are needed on some system and not on others ?

Comment: @Bob5421 because that was a bug which was fixed in newer versions of bash. Nowadays `<<< $(...)` should be identical to `<<< "$(...)"` (specifically when used with `<<<`, not `$(...)` in general). I can reproduce your problem with bash-3.2, but not with newer versions.

Comment: Not with bash-4.4 ;-) So the change probably happened just  between the 2 versions. The new behaviour is documented in the manpage: "`[n]<<<word` ...  Pathname  expansion  and  word  splitting __are not performed__."

Comment: You don't need my permission ;-)

Comment: Updated the answer, thanks!

Comment: Yeah.. can reproduce in bash 4.2. Thanks.